# Expresso-store How to view order ID in paypal invoice

Tags: expresso-store

I've just upgraded a client from Expresso Store V1.6 to V2. They use Paypal Express.

Previously the Store would list the order number as a line item in the paypal invoice, but now it lists the products and doesn't mention the store order number.  They have requested this back as they use this order number to reference payments and deliveries, also sometimes people pay with cards not in their name so using the order number avoids confusion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version [2.5.0](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_2_5_0) of Store order id's are assigned after an order is completed.

> Changed the way order_id's are generated. Only completed orders are
>   given a order id. Order id's are sequential per site.

The easiest method would be to setup an email template for your site admins that sends the relevant order details from Store when an order is completed instead of relying on the PayPal payment emails.

This would allow you to also use any Store fields for things like order items, shipping/billing details too.

If you were to go this route you would need to use the [orders tag](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/orders_tag.html) pair.